# Hive via hue is working but not via hive cli on Cloudera Data Platform

Tags: hadoop, hive, cloudera, cdp, hiveserver2

I've been working on stabilizing the pre-prod environment for our enterprise, and surprisingly hiveserver2 is up, hive on tez is up, hive is up too. I can query on the hive via hue but not the hive cli. any input would be appreciated...

log:

```
23/12/21 16:01:53 [main]: WARN jdbc.HiveConnection: Failed to connect to datanode01:10000

23/12/21 16:01:53 [main]: ERROR jdbc.Utils: Unable to read HiveServer2 configs from ZooKeeper
Unknown HS2 problem when communicating with Thrift server.

Error: Could not open client transport for any of the Server URI's in ZooKeeper: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target (state=08S01,code=0)

Beeline version 3.1.3000.7.1.7.0-551 by Apache Hive
```

I've check the zookeeper namespaces and hive's one, it's done right. I check also the ports they are open and I'm able to communicate from the masternode where zookeeper is to the datanode where hiveserver2 is up (idk why they installed it there). I've also tried changing some configs on hive-site.xml but without any results

More info: LDAP is active

Edit: moreinfo